# How to Bypass branch protections rules for particular users

Tags: security, github

How to Bypass branch protection rules for particular users i.e a service user trying to commit to the master branch directly but the Status check branch protection rule is preventing it from happening.

I have tried the below options, but still blocks the service user to direct commits to master.

1. I have tried with a custom role that has the Bypass branch protections permission, allowing just the right amount of access.
2. To enforce branch protections for specific users and roles with the "Bypass branch 1 protections" permission, enable "Do not allow bypassing the above settings in your branch protection rules".
3. Status check is a feature in branch protection rules was blocking the commit to the master.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paywalled feature to **"Restrict who can push to matching branches"** in the branch protection rules, which is [only available for public org repositories or if you have a Team/Enterprise account](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#restrict-who-can-push-to-matching-branches).

If you these do not apply to you, then you will need to make do with the repository role that allows bypassing. This howether is not compatible with **"Do not allow bypassing the above settings in your branch protection rules"** for your use case as you mentioned.